# Reuse a Where condition

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have the following entity framework query:

```
IQueryable<Address> addresses = _context.Addresses
  .Where(x => 
    !(_context.Users.Any(y => y.AddressId == x.Id)) &&
    !(_context.Books.Any(y => y.AddressId == x.Id) &&
    !(_context.Shops.Any(y => y.AddressId == x.Id));
```

I use this Where condition very often ...

Is it possible to define the condition in some kind and reuse it in different queries:

```
IQueryable<Address> addresses = _context.Addresses.Where(AddressCondition);
```

I was considering using Expression and Func ...

The problem is that the condition uses DbContext (_context).

Comment: Does this even run in EF Core 3.1? That's an ugly query to begin with - it tries to emulate LEFT JOINS without JOIN. If the entities are related, use the proper relations and let the ORM generate the joins. This one is essentially three separate LEFT JOINs trying to find addresses without relations

Comment: How would the left joins be with a lambda expression? Could you give an example? That is what I was looking for and then to use an Expression<Func ...

Comment: Forget the lambdas and funcs. You don't need either, if you *didn't* use `DbContext` like this, you could just write a function that receives one `IQueryable<T>`, applies the `Where` clause and returns the result. The query needs fixing. It's trying to emulate 3 NOT EXISTS subqueries, which are *equivalent* to 3 LEFT JOINs with null checks. It's the ORM's job to generate those joins though. Frankly, it's probably *better* to use a SQL view or function for this instead of trying to emulate the SQL query through LINQ. LINQ is *NOT* a SQL replacement

Comment: It looks like the `Address` table has a 1:M relation with the Users, Books and Shops tables. To represent this, the `Address` entity should have Users,Books and Shops collections. That would allow you to write eg `Where(addr=>!addr.Users.Any() && !addr.Books.Any()...)`. Now, I can understand Shops and Users having an address, but *books*? What are you trying to do? If you want to find orphaned addresses, it's better to just write a view or stored procedure

Comment: Of course ... I miss that I could check it by the collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Address table has a 1:M relation with the Users, Books and Shops tables. Assuming the Address entity has Users, Books and Shops collections you could use `!address.Users.Any()` to find addresses with no matching User etc.

You can extract the entire operation into a function that receives the original IQueryable, applies the `Where` operator and returns the new IQueryable, eg :

```
IQueryable<Address> OrphanedOnly(IQueryable<Address> query)
{
    return query.Where(address=>!address.Users.Any() &&
                                !address.Books.Any() &&
                                !address.Shops.Any());
}
```